# Assume you have 100 identical balls labelled y= 1, 2, . . . , θ. don't know their exact number. How to calculate MLE for θ?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, maximum-likelihood

There are at most 100 identical balls in a bowl, but we don’t know their exact number. However, we know that the balls are numbered with numbers 1, 2, . . . , θ
and each of the numbers from the number one to number θ is used exactly once and the
$θ ≥ 1$ is an integer. We pick a single ball at random. Let Y be the number in a ball
we pick at random. I have to calculate the MLE estimate for θ. Suppose that we pick a ball number 57.

My attempt:

PMF: $1/θ$

Joint PMF: $1/θ^n$ and thus MLE function would be $-n*log(θ)$ and by deriving and setting the function equal to zero, the function would achieve the maximum. However, when trying to find the maximum I get that $θ = null$ which isn't possible. Does this mean that the MLE estimator is equal to 57 so that $θ=57$?

Comment: This is known as the [German Tank Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem)  Well, for the general problem it is usually imagined that you look at a few samples.

Comment: Yes, the probability of picking the number 57 from the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ is maximized when $n=57$.